# What are the general differences between how one should train Type I vs Type II fibers?

Tags: endurance, muscle-endurance

Based on my latest readings, I have become more aware of the difference between Type I and Type II muscle fibers. In particular, I had not realized that Type I fibers support long distance / endurance activities. I had been under the impression that doing a low number of reps (say 5) would target Type II whereas more reps (say 15) would correspond to Type I. But it would seem this belief was perhaps mistaken.

1. Does weight training improve Type I fiber performance?
2. If it does not, how does one train Type I fibers?

Answer (score 1):

Weight training can improve Type 1 fiber performance if you focus on training that is more endurance related.

Type 1 fibers, called 'slow twitch' are generally harder to fatigue and used more for endurance.  Training can impact these fibers if we design our workouts to be more about higher rep ranges (which generally means lower weights).  If the goal would be to be able to handle more hamstring endurance to improve sports outcomes, then doing 10-20+ reps of a Romanian Deadlift might be a good choice.

Type 2 fibers, called 'fast twitch' are better for more explosive contraction of our muscles but fatigue much more easily.  Strength training is generally more geared towards this with rep ranges of 3-10 with a focus on explosive contractions.  Someone wanting to train hamstrings in this manner could choose a Sumo Deadlift for a set of 3 with a heavier weight.

Type 2x fibers, called 'fastest twitch' are a different fiber that your most powerful of all.  These are the fibers that we want to train with explosive actions.  This could be trying to take a moderate weight on a deadlift and exploding through the contraction as fast as possible.  However, these fibers will tired out very fast, so be careful of any high rep ranges.

A good resource for more information on this topic is with [Shredded Sports Science's YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/c/ShreddedSportsScience/videos) and [he did a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTwt7aCRGv4) with Omar Isurf about this topic that should also help.